# matlab code to java

Tags: java, matlab

Having the following code in Matlab:

```
r=  zeros(10,10);
r(:) = x(z);
```

given that "x" is a single dimension array and "z" is a 2d array what is the function
`r(:) = x(z);` doing and how could I implement something similar in Java?

Comment: what do you need? an array containing a 2d array? Please be clearer and you will get your answer quickly. :)

Comment: well first I would need somebody to explain what x(z); does as I found some code in Matlab and want to implement it in Java but I don't know what it is exactly doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, x(z) takes each element in the 2d-array z, and uses it as an index to fetch data from x.

For example x=[1 2] z = [1 1; 1 2] would give the result x(z) = [1 1; 1 2] because x(z) is really [x(z(1,1)) x(z(1,2)); x(z(2,1)) x(z(2,2))]. Therefore you have to be careful that the values in z doesn't exceed the size of x or you'll get index out of bounds.

r(:) = x(z) is basically the same as r = x(z).

To implement this in java you would need som kind of for-loop over the elements in z. In this loop you would construct a 2d-array by assigning the current index (i,j) with the value in x(z(i,j)).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

So the java code looks as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {
             for (int j = 0; j < z[0].length; j++) {
                y[i][j] = x[z[i][j]];
            }

        }
```